# php - create new objects inside loop and execute functions

Tags: php

i have some problem, i try to execute function on my object inside a foreach loop but i get error.
in the line: $data_scrape->scrape($key); in the second php file i try to call the function but I can't access the function. Which way to deal with the problem?

i have a class that call scrapeWeb.php:

```
<?php
require ('vendor/autoload.php');

use Goutte\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;
$test_array = array();

function scrape($value_to_search)
{

global $test_array;
$goutteClient = new Client();
$guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient(array(
    'timeout' => 60,
));
$goutteClient->setClient($guzzleClient);

$crawler = $goutteClient->request('GET', 
'someurl'.$value_to_search);


// Click on the "Security Advisories" link
$link = $crawler->selectLink('Article')->link();
$crawler = $goutteClient->click($link);


// Get the latest post in this category and display the titles
  $test = $crawler->filter('div > div > div > p')->each(function ($node) {
    # print ($node->text()) ."\n";

    global $test_array;
    array_push($test_array, $node->text());
});

return $test_array;

}

?>
```

and more class that call terms.php:

```
<?php include 'scrapeTest.php'?>
<?php

foreach ($top_words as $key => $value) {
   $data_scrape = new scrapeTest();
   **$data_scrape->scrape($key);** **<------ THIS LINE DON'T WORKING.**
   echo "<p>{$key}-</p>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: You might want to start by defining the function inside of a class in order to create an object. You also reference scrapTest.php but call the file above scrapWeb.php.

Comment: **scarpWeb.php** is not a class, it is a function so `new scrapTest()` will not work.